# Execute update in the same time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

I have two tables - users and codes. I need to insert user and allocate for created account one first free (not alocated - id_user=0) row with code (prize).

Below I attach my code. Do you think thats enough to ensure that there will not be situation where one code will be allocated to more than one user ?

I mean if one row will be taken in the same time and in result only one user will take the prize ?

```
     try {
                $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

                $result = $this->pdo->prepare(
                        "INSERT INTO `users`(`id`, `fn`, `sn`, `email`, `city`, `cdatet`, `ldatet`, `active`, `hash`) VALUES (0, :fn, :sn, :email, :city, now(), now(), 0, :hash)");
                $result->bindParam(':fn', $fn);
                $result->bindParam(':sn', $sn);
                $result->bindParam(':email', $mail);
                $result->bindParam(':city', $city);
                $result->bindParam(':hash', $hash);
                $result->execute();

                $lastId = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();

                $result2 = $this->pdo->prepare(
                        "UPDATE `codes` SET `id_user`=:uid WHERE `id_user`=0 ORDER BY `class` DESC LIMIT 1");
                $result2->bindParam(':uid', $lastId);
                $result2->execute();

                $this->pdo->commit();
                return $lastId;
    } catch (PDOException $e)  {
                $this->logError($e->getCode(), $e->getMessage());
                $this->pdo->rollBack();
    }     
    return 0;
```

Comment: The transaction should protect you against the multiple assignment scenario, so yes, probably this will work.